# Activity flags on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, flags

Just a quick question, as I couldn't quite understand it from the documentation.

If I set a flag - any flag, or several flags - on an `Intent` prior to launch, is this flag cleared when the `Activity` starts or is it persistent? What I mean is that let's say I have an `Intent` and apply  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to it - it will launch with this flag every time, or just once after I set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flag will be applied if you start your Intent where you set the Flag. The flag is not bound to your activity but to your Intent object. Therefore the flags are applied if your use the Intent to start the activity.

Comment: But if I keep the Intent object, will the flag persist? From the general tone I take it that it's not advisable to keep Intents.

Comment: @IgorK. in general if you save any object, it will also keep its attribute with it..so Yes.

Comment: Damn. Oh well, I'll kill the Intent then. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Every Time if you set the flag in **android:launchMode** attribute of activity tag in Manifest.

If you explicitly create Intent, set Flag and start activity then It will be applied only when you start activity with that Intent or new Intent with flag.